# R barplot colour not working with matrix

Tags: r, shiny

In my app I want the user to be able to produce a bar chart, selecting only the rows they want to use. I have done this using a matrix but when I try to colour the chart it does not work.

Here is an example file that could be uploaded:

```
Name    Score
Bob     4
Fred    1
Gary    2
Mary    5
Pete    7
```

In my simplified example below I plot all rows with height of "Score", when done using `inFile()[["Score"]]` I am able to colour the bars fine. But when using `as.matrix(t(inFile()[c(1:5), "Score"]))` all bars are the same colour.

Is there a way I can plot bars of different colours when the user specifies both rows and columns in base R *(project shows different plots from different packages, for this plot I want to only show base R)*

Full example:

server.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  inFile = reactive({ return (read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE))})

  output$plot = renderPlot({
    barplot(
      #inFile()[["Score"]],    #Colours correctly
      as.matrix(t(inFile()[c(1:5), "Score"])), #Only 1 colour

      col = as.matrix(rainbow(5)))
  })  
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Bar Plots"),
  sidebarPanel(
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
))
```

Sorry if this has been answered before, when searching I could only find people recommending using ggplot, but that is not suitable for this project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As for the plotting, this should work:

```
 barplot(
 inFile()$Score[1:5],
 col = rainbow(5))
```

I'm not sure why you want to use the data as matrix but when removing both as.matrix(inFile()) and as.matrix(rainbow(5)). The col argument is at least required to be a vector.In addition, using the dollar sign to extract the column 'Score' is a bit cleaner in my opinion.

For the input from user part, maybe inside your renderPlot:

```
 file=inFile()[,input$nameofcolumn]
 min=as.numeric(input$minrowvalue)
 max=as.numeric(input$maxrowvalue)
 barplot(
 file[min:max],
 col = rainbow(5))
```

Hope this helps!